# Find a word with regex formula every time the next character it's different by a letter/number or underscore

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation, regexp-replace

I need to find the word 'hello' every time that the next character it's different by a letter or a number or underscore.
In the image below there is an example (green it's ok):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N44iY.png)

How can I do it using a regex formula?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There is the regex you're looking for :

```
hello[^\w]{1}
```

"Catch the word hello if he isn't followed by a letter, a number or _".

Live exemple : https://regex101.com/r/1vzn8m/1/

Comment: Thanks, very useful :-) But I don't want to select next character after 'hello' when it's different by a letter,number or underscore. Just 'hello', it's possible?

Comment: Sure, you can catch only hello using capturing group : ```(hello)[^\w]{1}``` "hello" will be stocked in $1.